# What is wrong with this program in c++ which states: Print the quantity rows of the matrix if the rows have more that two odd numbers?

Tags: c++

This is the main function which prints the quantity of the row which have 2 or more odd elements

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
bool if_odd(int [], int);

int main()
{
    const int N = 3, M = 2;
    int i, j, a[N][M], k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];
```

This code block calls the function, checks whether the rows have 2 or more odd numbers

```
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if(if_odd(a[i], M))
            k++;
    }
    cout << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This function checks whether two or more elements of the row are odd

```
bool if_odd(int a[], int b) {
    int i, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        if(a[i] % 10 != 0)
            k++;
    }
    if (k >= 2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why look for modulo 10? Surely, `if(a[i] % 10 != 0)` should be `if(a[i] % 2 != 0)`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(a[i] % 10 != 0)
```

That line in the is_odd_function will test whether a number can be evenly divided by 10, not by 2, since it is a decimal number.